# xmldsig php do not add signing info in XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-signature

sorry of my English :) .
I neeed to write signing block in XML like it:

```
ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311"/>
<ds:Reference>
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311"/>
<ds:DigestValue>drvEZVSz3nSXHVI6+iRSDXZDGud9Ay56LLfMkpQkRp4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>/4ASSFXCsdsdMuwM9kw0riDbhhtLR/+UKZKNO51HbACu5DM
SLmmAmp5FwFHdsGtBQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
```

I find this in GIT : https://github.com/Maks3w/xmldsig
my code is:

```
        $data = new DOMDocument();
        $data->load(__DIR__ . '/newdata.xml');
        $xmlTool = new FR3D\XmlDSig\Adapter\XmlseclibsAdapter();
        $xmlTool->setPrivateKey(file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\EgovPayments\private1.pem'));
        $publicKey=$xmlTool->getPublicKey();
        //echo 'public key is:'.$publicKey;
        $xmlTool->setPublicKey($publicKey);
        $xmlTool->addTransform(FR3D\XmlDSig\Adapter\AdapterInterface::ENVELOPED);
        $xmlTool->setCanonicalMethod('http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#');
        $xmlTool->sign($data);
        $data->saveXML();
```

But nothing changed in newdata.xml, how it work with xmldsig in PHP?
thx

Comment: And what about ghost, how i can make signature with ghost method?

Comment: <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311"/>

Comment: interested in this, too.

Answer (score 0):

The function DOMDocument::saveXML() returns string. It is not to update file.
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Answer (score 0):

i've got the same problem - but find the following function "insertSignature" in the seclib.

if you use the Adapter add the following line to the end of the verify-function:

```
$objXMLSecDSig->insertSignature($data->getElementsByTagName("Security")->item(0));
```